# How to separate JSON keys and values in shell using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a json output file which contains the following output. I'm trying to get the value for the "status" keys but it did give me answer as `null` all the time using the following command.

```
cat output.json | jq -r ".status"
```

output.json

```
{
  "executions": [
    {
      "executionArn": "execution:job-execution:1ddb41e1-0d71-4dde-9cd0-d55119be334d",
      "stateMachineArn": "stateMachine:job-execution",
      "name": "jjfjnsldfnowef",
      "status": "RUNNING",
      "startDate": 1609918173.79
    },
    {
      "executionArn": "execution:job-execution:c07927bc-d871-4996-a58a-f9c89cbd351f",
      "stateMachineArn": "stateMachine:job-execution",
      "name": "c07927bc-23jjfnjfjs",
      "status": "RUNNING",
      "startDate": 1609918124.174
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help me to get that expected output below.

```
"status": "RUNNING"
"status": "RUNNING"
```

Comment: `jq '.executions[]|.status'` would give you the values, without keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can get something pretty close with this code:

```
cat output.json | jq "{status: .executions[].status}"
```

Explanation: `cat output.json | jq ".executions[].status"` would filter all elements of `executions` for the "status" field, and return the values as a list. But you don't want a list, you want a collection of field/value pairs. You can make that manually by creating an object with `{key: any query that creates a value}`.

The output is:

```
{
  "status": "RUNNING"
}
{
  "status": "RUNNING"
}
```

If you want to build strings instead (to get almost the exact output you asked for), you can do it by creating a formatted string with your "status: " text, also containing the query that will be interpolated.

```
cat output.json | jq '@text "status: \(.executions[].status)"'
```

The output is:

```
"status: RUNNING"
"status: RUNNING"
```